Central projection of $\mathbb{E}_3^{\star}$
Let $\mathbb{E}_3^{\star}$ be the extended euclidean space. Given a plane $\alpha$ and a central projection $\psi:\mathbb{E}_3^{\star}\backslash\{S\}\to\pi$, how do I prove that $S\in\alpha\Leftrightarrow \psi(\alpha)=\alpha\cap\pi$? This seems obvious  but I fail at describing my visual proof mathematically. Any ideas?
